# Rails: can ActiveRecord method "destroy" go wrong and not be performed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing an app in RoR, and I was wondering if following if statement should be put there:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[destroy edit]
...
  def destroy
    if @article.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Article deleted'
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Failed to delete the article'
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end
  end
...

private

  def set_user
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.id == @article.author_id
      @author = current_user
    else
      redirect_to article_path(@article), message: 'You can\'t do that'
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible for "else" branch i destroy method to be called? I am writing specs for that controller and I can't possibly think of the way to test that code.
I used the same approach as with ".save", but there we are dealing with DB validation. If there is no way "else" can be called, I will just delete those lines.

I something goes wrong with searching for the article owner or finding the article by id, error is gonna be present earlier, in "set_user" method.

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922233/activerecord-destroy-method-returns-a-boolean-value-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: It can not destroy article if the article is not present or you can add some other restrictions

Comment: @FranMartinez thanks, that's exactly the answer I was looking for :)